# Selenium cannot click menu-item from bootstrap dropdown

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1']"));
        action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
        WebElement tmpElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1']"));
        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tmpElement);
        List<WebElement> dd_list = driver.findElementsByXPath("//*[@id='masterNavigation']/ul/li[1]/ul/li"); 
           for (WebElement ele : dd_list) 
           {     
              System.out.println("Values " + ele.getAttribute("innerHTML"));     
              if (ele.getAttribute("innerHTML").contains("Event Dashboard")) {                   
                 ele.click();                                        
                 break;  
              } 
           }    
    }
```

Hi I am trying to Automate bootstrap drop-down menu. It's visibility is hidden by default.Once you hover mouse on it, its visibility property shows visible.I am able to click on drop-down , but after clicking on drop-down my selenium script is not selecting value from drop-down.

> Error: Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Cannot click on
>   element

**HTML Code Snippet**

```html
<a class="ui-button-text-icons" id="ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1" href="javascript:void(void);">
    <span style="padding-right: 1.3em;">Dashboards</span>
    <span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span>
</a>
<ul style="visibility: hidden;">
    <li class="first featureGranted">
        <a href="ClassicDashboard.aspx">Classic Dashboard</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: HTML code: '<a class="ui-button-text-icons" id="ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1" href="javascript:void(void);"><span style="padding-right: 1.3em;">Dashboards</span><span class="ui-button-icon-secondary ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span></a>
<ul style="visibility: hidden;">
   <li class="first featureGranted">
    <a href="ClassicDashboard.aspx">Classic Dashboard</a></li>
  </ul>'

Comment: Please format the HTML in your question

Comment: @NehaDixit As you mentioned `visibility is hidden by default` and on mouse hover `visibility property shows visible` so you are able to click which is a DropDown, Now for your script to select a value from drop-down you have to read the properties of the DropDown elements and select them accordingly. If it results in `ElementNotVisibleException`, you have to slow down a bit. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few things

- You don't need to traverse though all **li** elements to find your desire element you can do it with Xpath
- I have no Idea why you are using JavaScript to click first Element, but unless click method provided by Selenium is not working I would suggest not to use JavaScript Click
- Error suggests that element is not visible, it could be due to multiple reasons. You could wait using Explicit wait until element is visible as mentioned below. it might resolve your issue

**Code**

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1']"));
action.moveToElement(we).build().perform();
WebElement tmpElement= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_Sitemap1_HyperLink1']"));
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
// I have no idea why you are clicking using JavaScript
js.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", tmpElement);

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
WebElement eventDashboardMenu = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[contains(text(),'Event Dashboard')]")));
eventDashboardMenu.click();
```

Comment: Above solution seems to be working for me. But not always. It worked for 2-3 times, mostly it doesn't. Do you have solution for this problem.

Comment: For 20 sec time: Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 20 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath. For 30 sec time. same error appears

Comment: it could actually be taking more than 30 seconds. you can put try/catch and take the screenshot and check if element is actually visible or not ?